# How to control the name of the HTML control generated by Coded UI in the result log?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

We are using [Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#VerifyingCodeUsingCUITCreate) to create UI automated tests on Visual Studio and generate [Coded UI Test Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159363.aspx) for a **Web application**. These logs are inspected by product owners and system testers (people that do not have a technical background).

What's the hierarchy used by Coded UI to identify the name of the control that is used to generate the control name on the Log?

Is there a way to obtain control over the nomenclature and define more user friendly names for the controls in the log?

I tried to use Aria attributes in the HTML to generate a more use friendly control name, but it seems like aria attributes are not considered in this process!

--

## Edit

The macros are hand coded using JQuery instead of search properties. I've just tested that I can change the friendly name via the macro builder, but changes on Friendly names are saved only in the UIMap.test Xml and they are not reflected on the designer.cs file, which gives me the impression that I can't change it programmatically. Is there a way to change programmatically or at least without all that Xml? I just want a banana, but this UIMap.test Xml is like the banana, the gorilla and all the forest itself!

Comment: When the `UIMap.uitest` file is saved the `UIMap.Designer.cs` file is regenerated. So any renames will be done. When the rename is done in the UIMap editor you should get a popup explaining that the rename will need to be done manually in any other files.

Answer (score 1):

Controls can be renamed in UI Map editor. The context (right click) menu on the entries in the "UI Control Map" section of the editor has a **Rename** command. There is also a command icon for rename. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that the macros are hand coded using JQuery instead of search properties. I've just tested that I can change via the macro builder, but the changes are not reflected on the designer.cs file. It changes only the UIMap.test Xml. Is there a way to change programmatically or at least without all that Xml? I just want a banana, but this UIMap.test Xml is like the banana, the gorilla and all the forest itself!